# Exception caught by widgets library :Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

this is my code

```
class _AdminLoginScreenState extends State<AdminLoginScreen> {
  var _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var emailController = TextEditingController();
  var passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0XFFE4C9E5),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: false,
              child: Form(
                key: _formkey,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                        left: -30,
                        right: 275,
                        top: -175,
                        bottom: 100,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: Color(0XFFFEB06A),
                          ),
                        )),
                    Positioned(
                        left: 275,
                        right: -40,
                        top: 100,
                        bottom: -350,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: Color(0XFF36D6E7),
                          ),
                        )),
                    Positioned(
                      left: 37,
                      right: 37,
                      top: 200,
                      bottom: 100,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      //  children: [
                      // Flexible(
                      //  child: Padding(
                      //  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      //   horizontal: 50,
                      // ),
                      // child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 300,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "LogIn ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 35,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: Color(0XFFD3D3D3),
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: emailController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              labelText: 'Email',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0XFF4D4C4C),
                              ),
                            ),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null ||
                                  value.isEmpty ||
                                  !RegExp(r'sidra@gmail.com')
                                      // r'^[\w-\,]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,4}'
                                      .hasMatch(value!)) {
                                return 'Please enter correct email';
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: Color(0XFFD3D3D3),
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                              controller: passwordController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    borderSide:
                                        BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Password',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0XFF4D4C4C),
                                ),
                              ),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                    !RegExp(r'^[a-z A-Z 0-9]+$')
                                        .hasMatch(value!)) {
                                  return 'Please enter correct password';
                                } else {
                                  return null;
                                }
                              }),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 300,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              color: Color(0XFFFEB06A),
                            ),
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
                                  /* LoginCubit.get(context)
                                                              .userLogin(
                                                            email: emailController.text,
                                                            password:
                                                                passwordController.text,
                                                          );*/
                                  /*BlocProvider.of<LoginCubit>(
                                                                  context)
                                                              .userLogin(
                                                                  email:
                                                                      emailController.text,
                                                                  password:
                                                                      password.text);*/
                                }
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'LogIn',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: ((context) => ForgotPass())));
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'Forgot Your Password?',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 150,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    //  ),
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
                //  ],
              ),
            ),
            // ),
          ],`
```

and this the exception

```
Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type StackParentData.

Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Flexible widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Flexible is currently placed inside a Stack widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  Padding ← Flexible ← Stack ← _FormScope ← WillPopScope ← Form-[LabeledGlobalKey<FormState>#ac9e2] ← _SliverFillRemainingWithoutScrollable ← SliverFillRemaining ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#93db6] ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

note that i alredy deleted  flexible and padding widgets

Comment: I copied your snippet and couldn't reproduce the problem. Can you [edit] your question to include the exact snippet causing the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `Column` widget with `Positioned.fill` fill Column in stack widget.

```dart
Positioned.fill(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(// just in case if you need
    child: Column(
```

Use position widget `Align` or `Positioned` as a stack child.

Answer (score 0):

This falls under one of the common flutter errors.
[Incorrect use of ParentData widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/common-errors)